# What are the standard ways to manage free and paid Android app?

Tags: android, google-play

Currently I have a paid app published on Google Play, and a free version of the same app is being developed.

The question is, if the user has free version installed, and then installs the paid version; will the user end up with 2 versions? If yes, is this usual when it comes to user experience? What are the standards (Android market) ways to uninstall free version after purchasing paid version apart from in-app billing?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the package name is different you can upload free, paid and more of your apps. Each app will be treated as different apps.

Its upto you to continue to give updates as u give for paid apps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at some of the in-app billing related best practices at:

1. http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html (search for "billing")
2. http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/billing_integrate.html (search for "best practice")